# When I am in VirtualEnv and do apt-get install, is there any difference?

Tags: apt, python

If I have a virtualenv activated when I do something like

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

should I expect different results than if I did it outside the virtual env?

Limited theory says no, but I'm not sure I'm aware of everything I should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) is Python-specific, so no: `apt-get` will operate in your whole system. Thus there will be no different results.